# Windows incremental backup script

Tags: windows, backup, scheduled-tasks

I'm from a linux background, and need to run an incremental backup script on windows. I already have a batch script which dumps my database into a file. What I'd like is to only keep backups for the last seven days in addition to one backup file per week for the last 4 weeks (for example). I presume it's possible to do something like this with the windows task scheduler and a clever batch script?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you could. But it would be a hell of a lot easier to use a VBScript or PowerShell application.

Comment: If you can put cygwin on your windows machine then you it would probably be easiest with cron and rsync.

Comment: Classic question for http://serverfault.com . The guys there deal with those exact problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) - `rsync` for Windows. It's free, and does a great job.

Answer (score 0):

**ntbackup** is a builtin Windows XP tool that can perform scheduled incremental backup.